# How to display English (region) language code on some of the pages?

Tags: sxa, multilingual

How to get the English (region) - English (region)  language code from Sitecore? I want to display the language code (EN for example) on some of the pages inside the `<div>` tag for example

```
<div>
  <p>The language you are using</p>
  <p>[Display language code - EN here]</p>
</div>
```

I know I can just type myself the **EN** in the `<p>` tag, but I want to do it dynamically to just show this `<p>` tag when user is on English (region) - English (region) version of the site

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Sitecore.Context.Language` to get the context language of the website.

In your case, you can use something like this:

```
<div>
  <p>The language you are using</p>
  <p>@Sitecore.Context.Language</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for respone, but I have a question. What is this going to give me the language code or? I want EN to display on the page

Answer (score 1):

You can get the language code from the below code in a view :

```
Context language is: @Sitecore.Context.Language
```

Output :

```
Context language is: en
```

Kindly have a look at the `DefaultLanguage` in `Sitecore.config` file.

```
<setting name="DefaultLanguage" value="en" />
```